# Visio: What is Auto-Create Ink Shapes?

Tags: microsoft-visio

Visio Professional 365 includes an **Ink** tab on the Ribbon. Nothing on the tab seems to work on my Surface Book 2, using the Surface Pen.

[image: The Ink Ribbon]

`Convert to Shape` and `Convert to Text` are *disabled*

`Auto-Create Ink Shapes` is checked, but does not achieve the desired effect.

My poorly drawn square has not auto-converted to a shape:

[image: Polygon not converted to a shape]

I have tried to load Shapes from the library to see if it helps Visio to auto-detect the type of shape I am trying to draw. This has no effect.

[image: Basic Flowchart shapes loaded into Visio]

How can I get these features to work as expected? Why doesn't it work like it does in my other O365 apps? [Convert Ink To Shapes in Microsoft Office](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXmNzNsEmoU))

[A search on Google for "visio 365 auto-create ink shapes"](https://www.google.com/search?q=visio%20365%20auto-create%20ink%20shapes) yields no relevant results. The same feature is heavily featured for searches on other O365 products. This seems strange considering Visio is the flagship diagramming tool.

Is my Visio broken or does this happen on all Visio 365 installs?